# Sublime Text: show current outer element name

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Having a long routines, one gets sometimes lost and it would be handy to know which **class/function** the **cursor is currently in** (without the need to scroll all the way up, looking for the first outer block declaration).
Any ideas how to get this in Sublime Text 3?

I'm mostly interested in a solution for Python, but I suppose there should be some general way (plugin?) to have this. I can imagine having the name written in the status bar, for example.

Comment: Did you ever find a way?

Comment: any update? vscode has sticky classes - looks epic

Answer (score 5):

If you press `accel-r`, or type `@` inside the `Quick-open files by name` command palette(`accel-p`), you can see the current method/routine name highlighted. All this is in the default key binding of course.

Edit: after looking around, I found [Function Name Display](https://github.com/akrabat/SublimeFunctionNameDisplay) which does exactly what you want. It shows the current function name in the status bar.

Comment: Yes, but I only see a function (not the class), and it's also a bit inconvenient to press accel-r just to see this information. If it's justified to show the info about line and column number in the status bar all the time, then I believe the class name is not less appropriate.

Comment: I found a package that does what you want. It only shows the function name though, not class name and function name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it is quite naive and limited. It does not track the end of a function (or class), and is easily confused by nested classes (which makes it unusable for Django models with Meta class defined).

Comment: The repository linked hasn't been updated in a while, and currently one of the features (class name display) isn't working. This [fork](https://github.com/andfaulkner/SublimeFunctionNameDisplay) fixes it beautifully, so I suggest linking the post to it. Hope it gets merged back to the original repo (I have no affiliation to neither).